# Facebook like button flyout reposition

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

We have a Facebook like button on a page that when clicked, the flyout layer initially is positioned correctly, then immediately positions itself far to the right, partially off the page.  This appears to be done by Facebook's javascript code. Is there any way I can prevent the repositioning from happening, or override the auto-positioning of the flyout?